# Are you required to submit an iPhone app with an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos

Can I develop just an Apple Watch app? Or is it required to develop both an iPhone (iOS) app and an Apple Watch app when submitting to the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now develop and submit an independent Apple Watch app without an iPhone app counterpart. watchOS now also features a dedicated App Store app, right on the watch.

- [Creating Independent watchOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/creating_independent_watchos_apps)

> ### Overview
>
> Apple Watch users have come to expect that the apps on their watches just work, even when they don’t have their iPhones with them. To ensure the best experience for all Apple Watch users, create an independent watchOS app that doesn’t require an iOS companion.